# Why doesn't my ListView's ItemContainerStyle update properly?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, styles, styling

I have a really simple problem. My code is as follows (create a simple WPF project called WPFTesting and drop this code in to test this out):

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTesting.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Name="MainGrid"/>
</Window>
```

CS:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Xml;

namespace WPFTesting
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        ObservableCollection<Message> messages = new ObservableCollection<Message>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.KeyDown += MainWindow_KeyDown;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                messages.Add(new Message(DateTime.Now, "This is a test.", false));
            }
            ListView listView = new ListView();
            CreateListViewItemStyle(listView);
            GridView gridView = new GridView();
            listView.View = gridView;
            GridViewColumn timeStampColumn = new GridViewColumn();
            timeStampColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Date");
            GridViewColumnHeader timeStampHeader = new GridViewColumnHeader();
            timeStampHeader.Content = "Time";
            timeStampColumn.Header = timeStampHeader;
            gridView.Columns.Add(timeStampColumn);
            GridViewColumn messageColumn = new GridViewColumn();
            messageColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Text");
            GridViewColumnHeader messageHeader = new GridViewColumnHeader();
            messageHeader.Content = "Message";
            messageColumn.Header = messageHeader;
            gridView.Columns.Add(messageColumn);
            Binding binding = new Binding();
            binding.Source = messages;
            listView.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
            MainGrid.Children.Add(listView);
        }

        int clickCount = 0;

        void MainWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (clickCount % 2 == 0)
            {
                messages[0].IsBookmarked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                messages.Add(new Message(DateTime.Now, "This is a test.", true));
            }
            clickCount++;
        }

        private static void CreateListViewItemStyle(ListView listView)
        {
            string xaml = @"
                            <Style  xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"" xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"" TargetType=""ListViewItem"">
                                <Setter Property=""BorderThickness"" Value=""0""/>
                                <Setter Property=""Margin"" Value=""0""/>
                                <Setter Property=""Height"" Value=""20""/>
                                <Setter Property=""Template"">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType=""{x:Type ListViewItem}"">
                                        <Border Background=""{TemplateBinding Background}""
                                                CornerRadius=""0"">
                                            <GridViewRowPresenter/>
                                        </Border>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding=""{Binding IsBookmarked}"" Value=""True"">
                                        <Setter Property=""Background"" Value=""Pink""/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>";
            StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xaml);
            XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
            listView.ItemContainerStyle = XamlReader.Load(xmlReader) as Style;
        }

        public class Message
        {

            public Message(DateTime aDate, String aText, bool anIsBookmarked)
            {
                Date = aDate;
                Text = aText;
                IsBookmarked = anIsBookmarked;
            }

            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
            public String Text { get; set; }
            public bool IsBookmarked { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that on MainWindow_KeyDown, I will set messages[0].IsBookmarked = true; on any even number of key presses, but this does not update its style, as it should now show up with a pink background, in the list view. However, adding a new message using messages.Add(new Message(DateTime.Now, "This is a test.", true)); seems to work without any issues, as its created with the IsBookmarked flag already set. My question is, is there any way to update this style the way I'd like it to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Message class needs to implement iNotifyPropertyChanged for the UI to be notified

[INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.aspx)